# ¿Cómo ejecutar con jquery una función al hacer click y al volver hacer click ejecutar otra función?

Tags: html, jquery

No he usado mucho jquery y no consigo hacer esto:

Tengo un li con id="play1" al hacer click en él: reproducir una canción y al volver hacer click en "play1" pausar la reproducción. Así siempre, reproducir /parar.

```
<li id="play1">



$( "#play1" ).click(function() 
{
    //si play1 click ejecutar audio1.play();
    //otro click en play1 ejecutar audio1.pause();
});
```

¿usar un contador?

Comment: $( "#play1" ).click(function(e) 
{ 
    if(e ==null){ audio1.play(); } else { audio1.pause();  
    
});  pero no me funciona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pon una bandera que indique el estado del reproductor. Puedes crear la bandera con JavaScript:

```
var playing = false;

$('#1').click(function() {
  if(!playing) {
    audio1.play();
    playing = true;
  } else {
    audio1.pause();
    playing = false;
});
```

O vía un atributo `data-`:

```
<div id="audio1" data-status="paused">...</div>
```

Y obtienes el atributo en el evento click:

```
$('#audio1').click(function() {
  var status = $(this).attr('data-status');
  if(status === "paused") {
    audio1.play();
    $(this).attr('data-status', 'playing');
  } else {
    audio1.pause();
    $(this).attr('data-status', 'paused');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO en JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/yuguwusene/edit?html,js,console,output)

Te dejo aquí un ejemplo elegante para poder añadir más filas de audios sin repetir una y otra vez el mismo código en jQuery.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.playAudio', function(){
 
  var whichAudio = $('#audio' + $(this).data('audio'));
  
  whichAudio[0].paused
  ? whichAudio[0].play() 
  : whichAudio[0].pause();    
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;  
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  cursor: pointer;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="playAudio" data-audio="1">Play audio #1</li>
  <li>-------------</li>
  <li class="playAudio" data-audio="2">Play audio #2</li>
  <li>-------------</li>
  <li class="playAudio" data-audio="3">Play audio #3</li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio1">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio2">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="audio3">
  <source src="http://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-4.mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacerlo es usar los métodos bind y unbind de jquery:

```
<li id="play1">play/stop</li>

$("#play1").bind("click", click_1);
var click_1 = function() {
  //tu código
  $("#play1").unbind("click");
  $("#play1").bind("click", click_2);
}

var click_2 = function() {
  //tu código
  $("#play1").unbind("click");
  $("#play1").bind("click", click_1);
}
```

De esta forma, adjuntas el evento click del elemento #play1 a click_1 al ejecutar el código y si se ejecuta click_1, se desvincula click_1 y se vincula click_2. Luego en click_2, se desvincula click_2 y se vincula click_1.